# Spring controller @RequestMapping not hitting at time while using jQuery ajax

Tags: ajax, spring

I have developed an web app using Spring MVC and jQuery ajax. At time I'm having problem with my ajax call; it's not hitting the specified request mapping but at times it hits it without any problem. I don't know where the problem lies.

Comment: using the new mvc testing features in spring 3.2 makes this kinda thng a lot easier to debug

Comment: Is there any error/warning in the logging system

Comment: We need more information to help you.  Post the code for the Controller request mapping and the jQuery AJAX call.

Comment: This abandoned question should be closed as missing a [mcve].